# Change the Multipart Boundary in a SwiftMailer generated email?

Tags: php, email, swiftmailer

Thanks for reading!

**I want to change the default multipart boundary string in a message generated by SwiftMailer**.

SwiftMailer seems to automatically generate the string, and includes the string "swift_v4...", like so:

```
--_=_swift_v4_135388916050b2b5889e516_=_

        ...Text Message Part...

--_=_swift_v4_135388916050b2b5889e516_=_

        ...HTML Message Part...

--_=_swift_v4_135388916050b2b5889e516_=_
```

I don't see anything in the documentation, but before I go digging around in the code, does anyone know a way to change this via the SwiftMailer interface?

Comment: Ehm, you want to hide the tool you're using to send emails? ;-)

Comment: @Jack - Yep, don't want to advertise my mail method. =o)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Judging from the [source code](https://github.com/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/blob/master/lib/classes/Swift/Mime/SimpleMimeEntity.php#L433), this can be done simply via `Swift_Message::setBoundary()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
  $message = Swift_Message::newInstance()           # Create the message
->setBoundary('Your boundary')
# more code
```